# How do I add multiple triangles to the same element?

Tags: css

I have a created a timeline of milestones that each have a circular image `(border-radius: 100%)`. I am giving a css arrow to each .milestone-image-holder element using the **:before** and **:after** pseudo elements. I would like to give an arrow to top and bottom of the element, but it seems that I can only do top *or* bottom, not top *and* bottom (two css arrows).

Here is my HTML:

```
<ul class="milestones">
   <li class="milestone-left">
      <div class="milestone-img-holder">
         <img src="/assets/images/page/about-us/our-history/timeline_2011.jpg" />
      </div>
      <h5>2011</h5>
      <p>
         Sample text
      </p>
   </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul.milestones li.milestone-left .milestone-img-holder {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: -80px;
    float: left;
}

ul.milestones li.milestone-right .milestone-img-holder {
    position: relative;
    margin-right: -80px;
    float: right;
}

ul.milestones .milestone-img-holder:after, ul.milestones .milestone-img-holder:before {
        bottom: 98%;
        left: 50%;
        border: solid transparent;
        content: " ";
        height: 0;
        width: 0;
        position: absolute;
        pointer-events: none;
}

ul.milestones .milestone-img-holder:after { 
        border-color: rgba(238, 59, 52, 0);
        border-bottom-color: #EE3B34;
        border-width: 3px;
        margin-left: -3px;
}

ul.milestones .milestone-img-holder:before {
        border-color: rgba(238, 59, 52, 0);
        border-bottom-color: #EE3B34;
        border-width: 9px;
        margin-left: -9px;
}


ul.milestones img {
    position: relative;
    width: 10em;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
    border-radius: 100%;
    border: 3px solid #ee3b34;
    background: #CCC;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jcS79/)

That css will add an css arrow to the top, and changing `bottom: 99%` to `top: 99%`, and `border-bottom-color: #ee3b34` to `border-top-color: #ee3b34` will add the arrow to the bottom, but I cannot have both arrows at the same time. Is it possible?

Comment: A Jsfiddle would be useful (with image) but I don't se ethis as unsurmountable. In idea of what this is supposed to look like would help enormously.

Comment: @Paulie_D Added a JSFiddle

Comment: You cannot set top and bottom and height, one of those needs to remain flexible. Create a 2nd class for your bottom arrow then apply both classes.

Comment: @nitsuj Check the updated answer please!!! It has a image preview too!!

Comment: `img-holder:after` and  `img-holder:before` are using the same values in your css. you must give different values for `:before`, like: `bottom:0%;` and switch borders to be down arrow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ul.milestones .milestone-img-holder:after {
    border-color: rgba(238, 59, 52, 0);
    border-top-color: #EE3B34;
    border-width: 6px;
    margin-left: -6px;
    top: auto;
    bottom: -6px;
}
```

Is this what you are expecting?

[image]

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/jcS79/2/

---

Removing the arrows on first and last child!

```
ul.milestones li:first-child .milestone-img-holder:before,
ul.milestones li:last-child .milestone-img-holder:after {display: none;}
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/jcS79/9/

Comment: Yes, that is what I have, but it should have the arrow on the bottom (pointing down) as well.

Comment: @nitsuj Please check the updated answer. Sorry, I posted the wrong fiddle!!! :( Check the version 2... :D

Comment: @nitsuj simply compare your JSFiddle code to his :-)

Comment: @nitsuj The difference I have put in the answer. I used after with `bottom`, instead of `top` and adjusted the `border-width`. That's all! :)

Comment: @nitsuj Make sure you check the second version. The image is wrong! :) http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/jcS79/2/

Comment: Perfect! Should have brought my headphones! I couldn't concentrate, and ended up copying both to two separate css documents and comparing with FileMerge!

Comment: Another question, I want to add something like `ul.milestones li:not(:first-child) .milestone-img-holder...` to not show the top arrow for the first li, and use `:not(:last-child)` to not show the bottom arrow for the last li. How should I include that?

Comment: Yes. I will send you the CSS for it! Wait... Need to meddle with the fiddle! :)

Comment: You need the css: `ul.milestones li:first-child .milestone-img-holder:before,
ul.milestones li:last-child .milestone-img-holder:after {display: none;}`

Answer (score 0):

[JSfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/jcS79/8/)

**Simplified CSS**

```
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.milestones {
    margin: 50px;
}
ul.milestones li.milestone-left .milestone-img-holder {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}
ul.milestones .milestone-img-holder:after, ul.milestones .milestone-img-holder:before {
    left: 50%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content:" ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    border:6px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
}
ul.milestones .milestone-img-holder:before {
    /* the top one */
    border-bottom-color: #EE3B34;
    top:0;
    -webkit-transform:translate(-50%, -100%);
     transform:translate(-50%, -100%);
}
ul.milestones .milestone-img-holder:after {
    /*the bottom one */
    top:100%;
    border-top-color: #EE3B34;
    -webkit-transform:translate(-50%, 100%);
     transform:translate(-50%, 0%);
}
ul.milestones img {
    position: relative;
    width: 10em;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 100%;
    border: 3px solid #ee3b34;
    background: #CCC;
}
```

Comment: Fixed,,,forgot the unprefixed transform

Comment: Thank you! It looks like this worked in your fiddle, but I already implemented Praveen's solution, and it worked too!